# How can I add text to a text box without over writing the current text?

Tags: javascript

I want the user to be able to click the button and add the text to the field and not overwrite it and be able to type text in as well.

How would I do this?

This is the code I have so far:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>myStG review</title>
</head>

<script>
  function ButtonClick_Test() {
    document.getElementById("result").value = ' We loved working with Joe and Lorelei';
  }

  function addNoOne() {
    document.getElementById("result").value = ' No one is better.';
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="We loved working with Joe and Lorelei" onclick="ButtonClick_Test()"> <br/>
    <input type="button" value="No one is better." onclick="addNoOne()"> <br/>
    <textarea type="text" id="result" rows="6" cols="60" onclick="this.focus();this.select()">
    </textarea>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As a note, you have two closing head tags (won't affect your question, but it'll make your site fail W3C validation)

Answer (score 3):

Use the += operator when assigning the value. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("result").value += ' We loved working with Joe and Lorelei';
```

Same thing for the other one

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated with += from another answer.
Change:

```
document.getElementById("result").value= ' No one is better.';
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("result").value += ' No one is better.';
```

```js
function ButtonClick_Test()
{
document.getElementById("result").value = ' We loved working with Joe and Lorelei';
}

function addNoOne()
{
document.getElementById("result").value +=  ' No one is better.';
}
```

```html
<br/>
<input type="button" value="We loved working with Joe and Lorelei" onclick="ButtonClick_Test()"> <br/>
<input type="button" value="No one is better." onclick="addNoOne()"> <br/>
<textarea type="text" id="result" rows="6" cols="60" onclick="this.focus();this.select()">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addNoOne()
{
var old = document.getElementById("result").value;
document.getElementById("result").value = old + ' No one is better.';
}
```